# How do we call this alternative to CDF: Distribution of outcomes

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $F(x)$ be a standard cumulative distribution function, associated with a continuous RV. It denotes the probability of random variable $\tilde x$ being on the left-hand-side of $x$:

$$ F(x) = Prob(\tilde x \leq x)$$

Among other features, we know that $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) \to 1$.

I am interested in a similar function, but I don't know it's name. Let $X(x)$ denote the mass at $x$ after a continuum of mass $M$ was drawn from the distribution $F$.

Now, denote with $G(x)$ the mass of outcomes below and up to$x$:

$$ G(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} X(x') dx'$$

We should have that $\lim_{x\to \infty} G(x) \to M$.

**How do we call $G(x)$?**

Comment: I don't really understand what your notion in the continuous setting even means. Your integral also doesn't work as written in the discrete setting; if you want to write it as an integral then you need a Dirac delta, or a non-Lebesgue measure, or a Stieltjes integral, or maybe some other possibilities, but it can't be a Lebesgue integral on the line. Without handling those issues it's hard to tell what I should tell you. As best I can tell, $G$ is an approximation of $MF$, where $M$ is the number of samples taken, so $G$ will not actually converge, and $G/M$ will converge to $F$.

Comment: @Ian yes, I have updated that a bit and removed the discrete part, I don't need to be that general. But is there a *name* for MF? Something like, say, outcome function/distribution function?

Comment: I doubt it; why would you name a multiple of something you've already named? I can see why you might name $G$, but I don't think it has a name either (the result is some kind of sampling distribution).

Comment: @Ian Here, I have "derived" $G$ through $F$, because it was the easiest way of explaining what I want. $G(x)$ doesn't have to be associated with a random process - it could as well be the distribution of a population over age $x$ - despite we don't think about people "randomly drawn into a specific age"